# How to add table data and display the output in single page

Tags: javascript, html

**Demo:**

I'm really sorry if my question is very novice as I'm very new to HTML & JS. I'm trying add two table data(Default value and Extra) and print the numeric output in the third column(Output)

Also I wanted to know if I hit the submit button can the updated page(with the third column updated) will populate on the same page

Hope I have conveyed it correctly, thanks.

```
<form name="CheckOn" >

<table BORDER="1">

<tr class="heading">
  <td>Items</td>
  <td>Default value</td>
  <td>Extra(if any)</td>
  <td>Output</td>
 </tr>

<tr>
  <tr>

    <td>Apple</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="26" size=15 name="apple">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="0" size=15 name="apple">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" size=15 name="apple">
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Mango</td>
    <td><input type="text" size=15 value="26" name="mango"></td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="0" size=15 name="mango">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" size=15 name="mango">
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>

<p><input type="submit" value="submit" name="subs"></p>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/za7wox59/1/

Comment: Your "demo" doesn't have any script provided.

Comment: @Chaska :Link `https://jsfiddle.net/za7wox59/1/` has the  HTML & CSS and not sure about the JS part though and where I'm seeking for a help

Comment: @Goku http://jsfiddle.net/Micio/V6HaA/557/

Comment: @Leo: Thanks a lot for your help, it worked :)

Comment: @Goku You are welcome :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think simply you have to iterate each `tr` and  do the sum of each `input` inside the `td`(skipping the result `td` only) .

**1.** Iterate for each `tr` inside `table`.

**2.** Do the sum of each `input` inside the `td` of each `tr`.

**3.** If `td` is having `result td` index then set the sum value.

**Here is working snippet:**

**Note:** **I have assigned `id` to table**.

```js
document.getElementById("subs").addEventListener("click", function(e){
e.preventDefault(); //Just prevent to form submit for demo.
var resultTD=3;
    $('#tblID tr').each(function() {
    var sum=0;
    $.each(this.cells, function(index){
     if(index==resultTD){
          $(this).find("input").val(sum);
      }else{
          $(this).find("input").each(function(index) {
              sum=sum+parseInt(this.value);
            });
      }
    });
   });
});
```

```css
tr.heading {
    display: table-row;
    font-size:18px;
   font-family:cursive;
    background-color:lightgreen;
    cursor:pointer;
 border-collapse:collapse;
 font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="CheckOn" >
<table id="tblID" BORDER="1">
<tr class="heading">
  <td>Items</td>
  <td>Default value</td>
  <td>Extra(if any)</td>
  <td>Output</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>Apple</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="26" size=15 name="apple">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="0" size=15 name="apple">
    </td>
 <td>
      <input type="text" size=15 name="apple">
    </td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Mango</td>
    <td><input type="text" size=15 value="26" name="SDK"></td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="0" size=15 name="SDK">
    </td>
 <td>
      <input type="text" size=15 name="SDK">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Banana</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="26" size=15 name="Banana">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" value="27" size=15 name="Banana">
    </td>
 <td>
      <input type="text" size=15 name="Banana">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
</table>
<p><input type="submit" value="submit" id="subs" name="subs"></p>
```

Comment: @NullPointer : When I run as html page from my desktop its not printing the final output, maybe I'm missing something ?
btw, really appreciate for the time and your help!!

Comment: @Goku  Export my codepen **https://codepen.io/NullPointerr/pen/yqKJqv** it is working

Comment: Thanks a lot !! Got it